# How to install kb-2999226 update on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am trying to run an installer that requires the existence of Microsoft update kb-2999226.

Using Windows update, all I get is that I got my system up to date.

Searching online, I have found that I can download the update manually, but there is no version for Windows 10 (only for Windows 7/8 which installation did not pass because of incompatible os version).

Any idea of how I can force my Windows 10 to install that update? Or make the installer 'believe' it is installed?

Thank you!

Comment: `This update allows Windows desktop applications that depend on the Windows 10 Universal CRT release to run on earlier Windows operating systems.` & `The Universal CRT is a Windows operating system component. It is a part of Windows 10. For Windows versions prior to Windows 10, the Universal CRT is distributed via Windows Update.`

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm trying to install a software that specifically mentions this update as not existing. I need a way to make it appear explicitly and not just a part of the operating system... Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your installer is broken. Please raise the issue with the provider of the installer.

Comment: I know it already. As I'm not expecting the provider to do anything about it especially for me in a timely manner, I'd really like to get an answer for what I'm after.